# Can GitHub Action Job continue from the state the previous job left (without artifact or complicated procedure)?

Tags: github-actions

I previously had a GitHub Action with a single Job that was doing 3 things:

- Build the .net application
- Run Unit Tests
- Run Integration Tests

Now, I splitted this job in 3 different ones because:

- I like to experiment
- I like to see the GitHub PR updating the steps separately
- **I can/want run the Unit and Integration tests in parallel** so the entire process can complete quickly

This is the current GitHub Action:

```yaml
name: Pull Request Checks

on: 
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, labeled]
  
jobs:

  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Buid VS solution
      id: build
      run: dotnet build "FSharp project/MyProject.sln" -c RELEASE

  unit-tests:
    name: Unit Tests
    needs: [build]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Unit Tests
      id: unit-tests
      run: dotnet test "FSharp project/UnitTests/UnitTests.fsproj" -c Release --no-build --filter "TestCategory!=SKIP_ON_DEPLOY"

  integration-tests:
    name: Integration Tests
    needs: [build]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Integration Tests
      id: integration-tests
      if: github.event.action == 'labeled' && github.event.label.name == 'pr:ready'
      run: dotnet test "FSharp project/IntegrationTests/IntegrationTests.fsproj" -c Release --no-build --filter "TestCategory!=SKIP_ON_DEPLOY"
```

Ideally the Integration Tests job run only when the PR is labeled "pr:ready" (this point has still to be tuned/solved maybe).

This entire process works.
**I had to duplicate the Checkout step in each job**, this means they are completely different "machine".
If that is true, why the `dotnet test` with `--no-build` is still able to work?
MS changed the behaviour of that flag, so  honestly I don't remember if the dotnet cli version is running here is able to reuse the possibly executed build or it runs a build if needed itself.

So I'm not entirely sure the Checkout results to have a completely fresh environment in "successive" jobs, and if this is the case... there is a way to reuse the previous "state" in a simple way (like a simple parameter, not using artifacts and similar stuff)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every GitHub actions job is run on a fresh virtual environment. The only way to get data/files/etc between jobs is artifacts. In your case, the solution would be to generate an artifact in the build job which can then be used in the two testing jobs in parallel. See this [issue](https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/19) on the checkout action repo asking the same thing.

So you could wrap up everything you need for the tests into an artifact and replace the checkout step in the test jobs with downloading that artifact.

As to why your `--no-build` tests work, that is hard to answer without knowing what exactly is being checked out.